# Javascript SDK not posting to facebook

Tags: javascript, facebook

```
        <script type="text/javascript">

        function SendToFacebook()
        {
            window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
                // init the FB JS SDK
                FB.init({
                    appId: '432036336937975',                        // App ID from the app dashboard
                    status: false,                                 // Check Facebook Login status
                    xfbml: true                                  // Look for social plugins on the page
                });


                FB.login(function (response) {
                    FB.api('/me/accounts', function (apiresponse) {
if (response.authResponse) {
        //simple user access token
        var accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken,
            ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest(),
            pageId = '1521533601413118';

        ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if(ajaxRequest.readyState === 4) {
                //print out the extended page access token
                alert(ajaxRequest.responseText);
            }
        };
        ajaxRequest.open('POST','generatePageToken.php?pageId=' + pageId, true);
        ajaxRequest.setRequestHeader('Content-type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
        ajaxRequest.send('accessToken=' + accessToken);
    }

                        var data = {
                            message: "mymessage test",
                            display: 'iframe',
                            caption: "caption",
                            name: "name",
                            description: "description",
                            to: '1521533601413118',
                            from: '1521533601413118'
                        };

                        FB.api('/1521533601413118/feed', 'post', data, function () {
                            console.log(arguments);
                        });


                    });

                }, { scope: 'manage_pages'});

            };
            // Load the SDK asynchronously
            (function (d, s, id) {
                var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
                if (d.getElementById(id)) { return; }
                js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
                js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
                fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
            } (document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
        }
        </script>
```

I get this error
"[object Arguments]{0: Object {...}, length: 1}" in my javascript console. Why is this? Also I should note that I want this posted as the PAGE  not as admin. Unsure of which it will do. I've been stuck at this for literally days so PLEASE can someone help?

I've read probably 100 threads from here and other places about this so I do realize this is a duplicate thread of sorts, but NO THREAD has yet to work for me. Want to link to me a thread? Probably already tried. I must be missing a setting or something. Please treat me like a complete beginning in this aspect - facebook API is so confusing.

Comment: Is that the whole error message or is there something else?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are familiar with the different Access Tokens of the Graph API. You need a Page Access Token to post "as Page". Apart from that it´s exactly the same API call. Here are some useful Links about the Tokens and how to get them:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens
- http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-access-tokens/
- http://www.devils-heaven.com/extended-page-access-tokens-curl/

The last Link explains how you create an Extended Page Tokens that is valid forever. You have to do this server side, but you don´t need the PHP SDK for it. It is a good idea to use the Page Token on the server only.

If you want to use the PHP SDK for the feed posting, here´s a tutorial:

- http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-php-sdk-4-0-tutorial/

About your code: You should initialize Facebook on page load and only call FB.login in your SendToFacebook function. Also check out "FB.getLoginStatus" in the Facebook docs, so you don´t need to use FB.login all the time.

Example call after getting the Extended Page Token (just an example, you may need to urlencode parameters like the message):

```
$appsecretProof = hash_hmac('sha256', $accessToken, $fbAppSecret);
//init curl
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'facebook-php-3.2');

//get extended user access token
$url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/' . $pageId . '/feed?message=whatever' .
    '&access_token=' . $pageToken;
    '&appsecret_proof=' . $appsecretProof;
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
$curlResult = curl_exec($ch);
```

Check out the other parameters in the docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.1/page/feed

Comment: THanks for responding. I have the access token that is in the form of APPID|APPSECRET

I just do not know where to insert it. Won't a random one be sufficient? When I make the redirect to my facebook.php page I'll only need an access code long enough to make the facebook post.

I'm willing to even pay someone to spoon feed me the solution. I'm so friggin done with this damned thing

Comment: that one is only an app access token. you will not be able to post something with it, it´s the most basic one. just take a look at the links i posted, it´s not very complicated but you really need a page access token to post as page. the blogposts even include full code examples for that. i highly recommend using an extended page token, so you don´t have to refresh it.

Comment: I thought that since an access code had just been generated I tried going to my facebook page and submitting my details, but no post has been made. UGh.

Comment: I changed my code to this
}, { scope: 'manage_pages', 'publish_content' });

I put the publish content there.

When I run my code now it gives me this error "SCRIPT5009: 'SendToFacebook' is undefined"

Comment: OK OK I GOT IT. One problem though, it's posting as my name (Ryan Reese) to my Codefundamentals page. I want it posting as Codefundamentals not as Ryan Reese. YESSSSSSSSSS

Comment: So I put that Javscript underneath my login facebook function and set instead of console.log() (as it is with the tutorial you linked for permenant access codes). I set it as alert. It's pulling up 404.php. I looked at the code I pasted in and it has generatePageToken.php. There is no mention in that link that I needed to make this page. WHAT DO I DO. HELP.

Comment: i highly recommend removing that access token from the comments...never ever post any access token in public...

Comment: there is no publish_content, what you need is publish_actions (and manage_pages, of course).

Comment: anyway, if it´s still posting as your name, then you are clearly not using a page access token. you should do the feed posting server side, not with javascript. don´t push the page token around, you don´t need it client side.

Comment: I thought I could do this without server side? Ugh. How do I use the access token correctly? Would you be willing to do it and I pay you? Im desperate.

Comment: it´s no big deal, i will add an example call to the answer

Comment: Thanks for the code in your above answer. Where do I put that though? Is that the generatePageToken.php? what is that sha256 in your example? spell it out for me please - I know I'm incredibly stupid but I understand almost nothing.

Comment: read the blogposts i posted from beginning to end, i think every bit of it is explained :) - should also be clear what that sha256 stuff is then. you can put it in generatePageToken.php or you can store the page token in a database and reuse it without the need to use generatePageToken.php next time you are posting. btw, i forgot the access token...lol...give me some minutes

Comment: ok so my generate blah blah.php script is LITERALLY the PHP from

http://www.devils-heaven.com/extended-page-access-tokens-curl/

with my page ID and variables set.

Now on my facebook.php page I now have this. the alert() comes back blank and I still post as admin not as page. see first post for updated code

Comment: yeah, because you are still using FB.api - don´t use the javascript api for this, check out the code in my answer

Comment: if it does not work, start debugging. with firebug or the chrome dev tools you can easily debug your php file, in the network tab. use some echo/var_dump/whatever to check out what´s wrong (IF there is something wrong). if you really post with a page token, it will get posted as page.

Comment: This is my setup.

facebook.php and the generateAccessToken.php. facebook.php is what I posted above. generateAccessToken.php is the php from the link

I have IE console up and nothing is being error flagged. The code you gave was a part of the link am I right? because that's a part of generateaccesstoken.php

Comment: debugging does not mean "check for error flags", it meany you have to use echo/var_dump/whatever to...well...debug ;) - and again, you are still using FB.api in your code, without any page token. make sure not to just copy code, you need to understand what you are doing and when to use javascript and php and all that jazz.

Comment: What would it cost to have you finish this up for me?

Comment: well, if you really can´t figure it out on your own, feel free to leave me your email. can´t even move this discussion to chat because you only got 1 reputation...lol

Comment: sportsdude(dot)reese(at)gmail(dot)com

to avoid the spam bots from getting it